# Android MpChart how to disable stacklabel?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Hello i need disable stack label, can u tell me the way to do it?
[image]

Comment: plz helpppppppppppp..... :(((((((

Comment: Try `mpChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);`

Comment: It work. thansk you :)

Comment: let post your question. I mark it, for another people who didnt know it sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable `Legend` in MP Android Chart, please add

```
mpChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: so simple for user who start to lean MpAndroidChart, thanks you.